# Encoded HTML to Decode But it's not correct formatting

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, c#-4.0

I have fetched some Encoded html from the database.While fetching i Decoded that html in somewhere.But Bold/Italic & other formatting not showing ,Only showing just text only.

My Code

```
    string a = da.GetLeftPanelData();//<-- in here Encoded html comes like &lt;p style=&quot;text-align: justify;&quot;&gt;

    string b = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(a);
    mypanel.InnerText = Regex.Replace(b, @"<[^>]+>|&nbsp;", "").Trim();
```

Comment: Your code strips the formatting out, why are you expecting it to display?

Comment: no.i just show here only a first line of code.

Comment: There are three lines of code, the third line strips all the formatting out.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Regex.Replace` call strips out all the HTML tags, and, therefore, all the formatting information.

**Elaboration**

Let's say string `a` read from the database is:

```
&lt;p&gt;Text can be &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt; or &lt;i&gt;italic&lt;/i&gt;.&lt;/p&gt;
```

Then the decoded string, `b`, is:

```
<p>Text can be <b>bold</b> or <i>italic</i>.</p>
```

The regex pattern matches every occurrence of `<`, followed by some characters, followed by `>`.  So the `Regex.Replace` call replaces every HTML tag (eg. `<p>`, `<b>`, `</i>`) with the empty string, and `myPanel.InnerText` becomes:

```
Text can be bold or italic.
```

Comment: pls elaborate more...

Comment: Can't we do it in Just straight? other than use Regex ?